# Should I use `id` or `_id` in graphql(apollo)

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

In many tutorials, they use `id` in graphql schema, but many databases default to use `_id`, so we have to map it in every model (graphql type - database entry).

So is there any huge advantage of anyone over the other one?

Which should I choose?

Comment: are you familiar with relay connections, and object identification

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with relay. I use Apollo, with which I have to write a resolver for every type and define the map from _id to id.

Comment: that's basically done for refetching the `node` object from main rootquery as explained below, try understand the sentences, code is just for illustration

Comment: can you put the `id` mapped by `_id` code